# We have $20$ different books with thickness $5$cm and $10$ identical ones whose thickness is $10$cm

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

**Problem:**

> We have $20$ different books with thickness $5$ cm and $10$ identical ones
> whose thickness is $10$ cm. Compute the number of ways , to put those
> books into $3$ shelves of length $2$ m , if no shelf should remain emtpy,
> and if the order of the books in the shelves does matter.

I initially thought:

Let's treat them at first as identical. We pick $3$ and put each in one shelf in $1$ way. We now have to distribute $27$ identical with $\displaystyle \binom{3+27-1}{27}$ ways , but since there are $20$ different and $10$ same there they can be actually rearranged in $\dfrac{30!}{10!}$ ways.

Total number: $\displaystyle \binom{3+27-1}{27}  \cdot \frac{30!}{10!}$

Do you agree? Any other suggestion?

Comment: Please include title in the body and not refer as "those" books

Comment: What does it mean to say, "If any shelf should remain empty?"

Comment: Am I missing something?  Or is every shelf long enough to accommodate every book by itself?  Why bother mentioning the lengths and thicknesses at all in this case then?  It would be a far more interesting problem if we had, for example, the shelves were only length $1$ meter instead implying that you are limited in space in each.

Comment: @JMoravitz  you are right there was another question before with some other clues and it was indeed needed, but I think he kept it that way , just for us to check if there is a hidden constraint

Comment: @JMoravitz do I ? please explain if so.. I assumed that  I pick randomly 3 books , and fill every shelf. That's why we only count possible ways to distirbute 27 books only and not 30 , and then ( now they are seperated into 3 teams (shelfes) I just rearrange them

Comment: Ah, I missed that you used $27$ instead of $30$.  In that case, it appears correct at a glance.

Comment: @JMoravitz okay if you have any other concern , please I am open, I am here to find my errors and imrpove!

Answer (score 1):

Each shelf could accept all the books. Therefore we don't have to bother about the capacity of the shelves.

That each shelf should contain at least one book is a difficulty of the problem. But you don't have approached this difficulty correctly: By choosing some three books beforehand you have introduced an asymmetry which is not easy to eradicate. any two of these books cannot be on the same shelf anymore, but a priori they could.

I'd argue in the following way: Put all $30$ books into a long line. This can be done in $N=?$ ways. Between these $30$ books there are $29$ spaces. We have to choose $2$ of these spaces to put  markers where the first and the second shelf ends.